# Conditionally change URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm learning about `.htaccess`, and have a file with the current rules:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Is there any way I can modify the `RewriteCond` to do only re-direct if the request does not end in `.png` or something else?

Comment: yes, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another `RewriteCond` to exclude certain conditions that you don't want rewritten. As [@acheong87](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925913/acheong87) stated, prefix `!` before the regular expression indicating that any files that match should fail.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(png|jpg|etc..)$
```

Answer (score 2):

Prefix your expression with `!`, like so:

```
RewriteRule !\.png$ /index.php [L]
```

The `$` is known as an *anchor*, and matches the *end* of the string.